# PRAW: Authorizing with OAuth prevents me from getting submissions/comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, reddit, praw

If I use OAuth, I am unable to get new submissions or comments from a subreddit.

My Oauth code looks like this:

```
import praw
import webbrowser

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent)
r.set_oauth_app_info(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI)
authURL = r.get_authorize_url("FUZZYPICKLES", "identity submit", True)

webbrowser.open(authURL)
authCode = input("Enter the code: ")

accInfo = r.get_access_information(authCode)
```

After that I can try to get submissions

```
submission = r.get_subreddit("test").get_new()
```

or comments

```
comments = r.get_comments("test")
```

but if I use either value, the program crashes with the error:

```
raise OAuthInsufficientScope('insufficient_scope', response.url)
praw.errors.OAuthInsufficientScope: insufficient_scope on url https://oauth.reddit.com/r/test/comments/.json
```

If I don't use OAuth, either by using `login()` or by just not authorizing, I have no such issues. I am using Python 3.4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wanted to make you aware that you may post your own answer under a question you asked. It's more organized and easier for anyone who's searching for the overall solution.

Comment: @Saroekin Thanks, this was my first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself. To read posts, you need "read" in your list of requested scopes. So, `"identity submit"` should be `"identity read submit"`.